# Unity3D - Changing animation states based on movement

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple AI (a simple ellipse), which switches between a walking animation and a standing animation, depending on whether or not it is moving.

I already have the AI set to follow and turn to the player, however I am having trouble finding out how to switch between animation states.

I have a Boolean parameter in the animator, "**`isWalking`**", which is set to switch to the walk animation if `true`, and switch to the standing animation if `false`.

My problem is how to 'check if the object is moving'.
I essentially want to write some code that does something like this:

```
If(object is moving) 
{
    isWalking == true;
}
else 
{
    isWalking == false;
}
```

I've searched on the web, but I've yet to find a solution.
I considered using `rigidbody.IsSleeping()` to see if the object is asleep, but I couldn't find any examples of how to use it.

I'm a complete newbie to both Unity and programming.

Thanks in advance. :)

[image]

[The object, as shown in the inspector window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slksf.png)

Edit:
I have tried this code, but there's probably something wrong with it. :/

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class aiscript : MonoBehaviour {

    NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform target;
    public Animator anim;
    Vector3 pos;
    public GameObject monmon;

    void Start () 
    {
        pos = monmon.transform.position;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
    }


    void Update () 
    {   
        pos = monmon.transform.position;
        Vector3 originalPosition = pos;
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        Vector3 difference = originalPosition - pos;
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", difference.magnitude > 0.5f);
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to post a sccreenshot of your `isWalking` boolean variable in the Animator Window? This will be helpful to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

From the `Animator` class, you can do that with the `GetBool` function and also set change the animation state with the `SetBool` function.

```
Animator myAnim;
```

.....

```
myAnim = GameObject.Find("ObjectAnimatorIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Animator>();
```

.....

```
if (myAnim.GetBool("isWalking") == true)
{
    //Is walking.....
}
else
{
    //Is not walking
}
```

You can even change the state of `isWalking` later on with

```
myAnim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
myAnim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, my object moves around the scene freely, following the player around. I need the animation to change to the standing animation when the object has stopped moving, and to the walking animation when it's catching up to the player. I need a way to check if the object has stopped moving or not.

Comment: I thought your question was about accessing `isWalking` variable from the animator?

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose your object has a Rigidbody attached to it to move, and the Animator.

If so, you just check the velocity vector in the rigidbody, and check it's magnitude to a specific threshold.

Suppose you have a threshold of 0.5f, This will mean that, if the object is moving in any direction at more than 0.5 unit/second, it's considered running, otherwise, it's standing.

```
Animator myAnimator;
Rigidbody myRigidbody;

void Awake() {
    this.myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    this.myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update() {
    myAnimator.SetBool("isWalking", myRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 0.5f);
}
```

**EDIT:**

To optimize it, you can save the hash of the boolean parameter of the animator

```
int isWalkingAnimationId = Animator.StringToHash("isWalking");
```

and then use that instead of the string.

```
myAnimator.SetBool(isWalkingAnimationId , myRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 0.5f);
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems you Rigidbody is kinematic, velocity will always be (0,0,0).
I guess you are changing the transform.position manually to move the object. If so:

```
Vector3 originalPosition = transform.position;
// Your manual changes on transform.position
Vector3 difference = originalPosition - transform.position;
myAnimator.SetBool("isWalking", difference.magnitude > 0.5f);
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work. :/
Maybe it has to do with the way my object components are set up? I've added a screenshot of the inspector window. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated the answer.
Your Rigidbody is Kinematic.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Comment: Thank you :)
I have updated the question with my attempt at using your advice :/